# Using Google Maps Directions in Android App

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-maps

I'm trying to develop an Android App to go with my web app [www.scroutenise.com](http://www.scroutenise.com), so I made a backend API to mimic the behaviour of the Javascript app which returns

1. A Google Maps DirectionsResult
2. A bunch of Google Maps Places

Both are in the same format provided by the Google Maps API. Great - with JS I can easily render this on a Google Map.

So far in my App I'm successfully communicating with the API and getting the full results - keep in mind the API is a WebSockets API so there's no URL - and I've got a Google Map showing.

The only thing I can't find documentation or tutorials for is how to display directions on the map. I'm sure I could figure out how to place Markers, but the directions aspect is a pretty important aspect of my app. Is it even possible? Are there some Ts&Cs that Google has to stop people from making a directions-related app?

Thanks for reading, I hope somebody can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get what you means by directions here, But you can draw path using the way described in this post.

http://csie-tw.blogspot.com/2009/06/android-driving-direction-route-path.html

Comment: This will do I suppose, as it seems showing directions on a map automatically is not supported. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In Android, you can specify driving directions through the use of an Intent:

```
String geoUriString = "http://maps.google.com/maps?" + 
   "saddr=" + srcLat + "," + srcLng + "&daddr=" + dstLat + "," + dstLng;

Intent mapCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(geoUriString));
```

Then based on the apps installed on your device (navigation, maps, etc) the user will be able to receive directions from one of those apps.

Comment: I actually wanted to include the directions *within* my app, but thank you.

Comment: How to add Directions from a Lat Long to the location of the USER

Answer (score 0):

```
String uri= "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/" + 
    fromLat + "," + fromLng + "/" + toLat + "," + toLng;

Intent mapCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
```

OR only location of "to" and user must turn on GPS:

```
String uri= "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//" + toLat + "," + toLng;

Intent mapCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
```